# SQL merging and cleaning up duplicate data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a database containing 3 tables:

```
---- Contracts --------------------------------------
[PK]ContractID
[FK]DebtorID
    Other (like DateStart, DateEnd, ContractStatus, etc.)
-----------------------------------------------------

---- Debtors ----------------------------------------
[PK]DebtorID
[FK]ContactID
    DebNr
-----------------------------------------------------

---- Contacts ---------------------------------------
[PK]ContactID
    ContactType (0 = person, 1 = company)
    ContactNote
    Name
-----------------------------------------------------
```

This is a pretty simple design. I used an old database and migrated the data into this new structure. The only problem is, that it requires a cleanup. A debtor with the same name occurs more than once, for example:

```
ContractID: 1 DebtorID: 1 ContactID: 1 DebtorName: Philips
ContractID: 8 DebtorID: 3 ContactID: 9 DebtorName: Philips
```

Obviously, these two debtors are the same, and therefore I fuzzy grouped and updated the same ContactID's into Debtors, with SSIS en T-SQL. So the new data example looks like this:

```
ContractID: 1 DebtorID: 1 ContactID: 1 DebtorName: Philips
ContractID: 8 DebtorID: 3 ContactID: 1 DebtorName: Philips
```

So 'Philips' only occurs once in the database, yet still two DebtorID's are referencing to the same 'ContactID', which is not ideal. Now I want to update the Contracts table so that it references to the same DebtorID, and so I can drop those multiples. So what I basically want to achieve is:

```
ContractID: 1 DebtorID: 1 ContactID: 1 DebtorName: Philips
ContractID: 8 DebtorID: 1 ContactID: 1 DebtorName: Philips
```

I wrote a T-SQL to achieve this, which is the following:

```
DECLARE @MINID INT
DECLARE @MAXID INT
DECLARE @DEBTORID INT
DECLARE @CONTACTID INT

/* ENTER ALL THE CONTACTID's INTO #TEMP1 WHICH OCCUR MORE THAN ONCE AND ADD A ROWNUMBER TO IT SO WE CAN GO DOWN THE LIST 1 BY 1*/
SELECT Row_number()
         OVER (
           ORDER BY ContactID) AS RNUM,
           ContactID AS ContactID,
           COUNT(*) AS AmountDuplicates
INTO   #TEMP1
FROM Debtors
GROUP BY ContactID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

SET @MINID = (SELECT(MIN(RNUM)) FROM #TEMP1)
SET @MAXID = (SELECT(MAX(RNUM)) FROM #TEMP1)

WHILE @MINID <= @MAXID
BEGIN
    /* SELECT THE CONTACTID OF THE ITERATION */
    SELECT @CONTACTID = ContactID
    FROM #TEMP1
    WHERE RNUM = @MINID

    /* SELECT THE LOWEST DEBTORID WHERE THE CONTACTID OCCURS MORE THAN ONCE */
    SELECT TOP(1) @DEBTORID = DebtorID  
    FROM Debtors 
    WHERE ContactID = @CONTACTID
    ORDER BY DebtorID

    /* UPDATE ALL CONTACTS WITH THIS LOWEST DEBTORID WHERE THE CONTACTID OCCURS MORE THAN ONCE */
    UPDATE C
    SET DebtorID = @DEBTORID
    FROM Contracts C
        INNER JOIN Debtors D ON C.DebtorID = D.DebtorID
    WHERE D.ContactID = @CONTACTID

    /* NEXT RNUM FROM #TEMP1 ITERATION */
    SET @MINID = @MINID + 1
END
DROP TABLE #TEMP1
```

Lastly, I'm deleting the debtors which have no reference anymore to the Contracts table.

```
DELETE
FROM Debtors
WHERE DebtorID NOT IN (SELECT DebtorID FROM Contracts)
```

I can confirm that this does the job, but out of curiosity, perhaps there is a lot easier way - with less operations and less of a detour - to achieving the same goal? I'm working in MS SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: You should be able to make use of Row_Number() and partition it by what makes your rows unique, and then delete those which number is larger than one.

Comment: So it's not necessary to insert the result in a temp table? The query remembers the data set till the end of the loop?

Comment: pseudo code as I don't have the time to make a fully functional fiddler - I hope it helps: `;WITH CTE AS (SELECT PrimayKey, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ContactID ORDER BY ContactID) AS RN FROM Debtors) DELETE D FROM Debtors D INNER JOIN CTE ON CTE.PrimayKey= D.PrimayKey WHERE RN > 1` - I'm thinking something like that should be possible. The complexity of the common table expression then would change given your actual structure.

Comment: Kind of new to CTE, but I will look more into it and figure out what your code exactly does. Thanks.